# Server Error in '/' Application. Value cannot be null Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I cant comprehend what might be the issue for this error on my local machine.
It says something to do with , virtualpath or something , but Ive tried researching , I really dont have the idea to begin with , since im quite still in  the pace of learning curve in .net

here is the main issue

> Server Error in '/' Application. Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   virtualPath Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: virtualPath
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   virtualPath]    System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath,
>   VirtualPathOptions options) +8956140
>   System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider.CacheLookupOrInsert(String
>   virtualPath, Boolean isFile) +31
>   System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider.DirectoryExists(String
>   virtualDir) +6
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.FileResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs
>   args) +105    (Object , Object[] ) +64
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters) +36
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +140
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +158
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain) +64
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args) +50    Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) +326
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

any recommendations where to start investigating this issue or what could be the culprit of this issue?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of .NET and compiling it against it?

Comment: hv u use any security systems...?

Comment: hv u use  any asp.net membership role provider?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what code and/or actions lead to this exception.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me in a batch handler and it was because I was recreating requests on the server without the virtual path.  I was hosting in local IIS off the default website so the path was `http://localhost/MYAPP/somecontroller`.  When I created the requests in the batch handler I was trying to execute `http://localhost/somecontroller`, which generated the error.

The code I was running server side was:

```
var requestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri, batchRequest.Url);
```

Which for local development I changed to be

```
var requestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri, batchRequest.Url.Substring(1));
```

batchRequest.Url would evaluate to /controller/method, removing the first slash caused the local app name to be kept in the path.